# MongoDB get documents fields description (like system tables in SQL)

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Do you know if it's possible to have a set of documents (ideally defined through aggregate & match) and then get metadata on the fields/ paths in those documents?

An example of what I mean. Considering this set of input documents:

```
[
  {_id:1, name:"John", age:"31"},
  {_id:2, name:"Jane"},
  {_id:3, product: { code:"abc", weight:"21"}
]
```

Then this function would ideally return something like:

```
{
  _id:3,
  name:2, 
  age:1,
  product {
    code:1, 
    weight:1
  }
}
```

That shows how often a particular path is found it the set of documents

Comment: You could either create a python script / javascript in the server and run it locally there, or store a JS in mongodb special collection system.js: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish your task is to use MongoDB Compass ( not MongoDB Compass community ).

For every collection you can make a schema investigation, but clicking on tab Schema, see the image below.

[image]

Once the schema has been analyzed, it can be exported by choosing share the schema as JSON, on the main menu, see the image below.

The result is the JSON document that contains all distinct values, as you looking for, see the image below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's indeed what I want, but I want to ship it as part of an application so be able to implement it myself so users can create their own queries (by selecting fields) based on the the metadata found.Anyway I could trace the queries Compass fires to create this?